# Using MEF in an editor

Tags: c#, mef

Im trying to developing editor like VS editor where i hawe components like FTP, TelNet (where you drag and drop in designer and connect them with each other change properties in PropertyGrid and so on) and then execute. Is good idea to use MEF to scan all dll-s that have interface IComponent and then use reflection to get the original Object from dll-s. example

```
[Export(typeof(ICOmponent))]
[MetadataExport("Name", "FTP")]
public class FTP : ICOmponent
{
    public string Server { get; set; }
    public void Start()
    {
        ....ConectTOServer(Server);
    }
}
[Export(typeof(ICOmponent))]
[MetadataExport("Name", "MessageBox")]
public class MessageBox : ICOmponent
{
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public void Start()
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(Message);
    }
}

public interface ICOmponent
{
    void Start();
}
```

Or is another method to get original object from MEF from ICOmponent like from Metadata.. because PropertyGrid nead real object for displaying properties for FTP Server and From MessageBox Message.
Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Looks good. But what is the question? Is there some part that you don't know how to implement? Was there a problem with how the propertygrid shows the objects? Some other problem?

Answer (score 0):

For `MEF` to work, any assembly/dll that is dropped on you application must implement `Exports`. If it does not, you won't be able to `Import` anything.

To work with assembly/dll that does not have any exports, use reflection to search for types that implement `IComponent`. And use `Activator` class to create instances from their type information.

Comment: But like you see i hawe for all my components hawe export also in main window i hawe importmany for all ICOmponents the problem with MEF is how can i get real Object example FTP from exported ICOmponent that i get from composition,.